# Angular ui-grid, how to limit or specify the number of rows

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have data in one json like this below:

```
$scope.myData = [
          {name: "john", age: 25},
          {name: "anne", age: 21},
          {name: "joe", age: 22},
          {name: "mary", age: 31},
          {name: "stacey", age: 25},
          {name: "martin", age: 21},
          {name: "fred", age: 22},
          {name: "harry", age: 31}
];
```

how do I split them into two grid tables, results below:

table 1:

```
 __________
| name| age|
|----------|
| john| 25 |
| anne| 21 |
| joe | 22 |
| mary| 31 |
------------
```

table 2:

```
 ____________
| name  | age|
|------------|
| stacey| 25 |
| martin| 21 |
| fred  | 22 |
| harry | 31 |
--------------
```

many thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/lk1Y69?p=preview

splice your data into two parts

```
$scope.data1 = $scope.myData.splice(0,4);
$scope.data2 = $scope.myData.splice(0,4);
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.myData = [
          {name: "john", age: 25},
          {name: "anne", age: 21},
          {name: "joe", age: 22},
          {name: "mary", age: 31},
          {name: "stacey", age: 25},
          {name: "martin", age: 21},
          {name: "fred", age: 22},
          {name: "harry", age: 31}
];

$scope.data1 = $scope.myData.splice(0,4);
$scope.data2 = $scope.myData.splice(0,4);

    $scope.gridOptions1 = { data: 'data1' };
     $scope.gridOptions2 = { data: 'data2' };
});
```

HTML:

`<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions1"></div>
         <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions2"></div>
    </body>`